# Angular 6 - run method in service every 10 seconds

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6

I have this service using HttpClient to get some data :

```
checkData() {
    return this.http.get('my url');
}
```

The on the footer component I call it and display the result :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myservice.checkdata().subscribe( result => { this.statustext = result } );
}
```

This works, but I need this method to be run every 10 seconds so it's up to date.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `rxjs` timer to call the api request at startup and then every 10s.

This is best achieved by using rxjs to divide and conquer.

Firstly, import the following:

```
import { timer, Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, takeUntil, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Then add the property to handle request to the api:

```
private fetchData$: Observable<string> = this.myservice.checkdata();
```

Next, add the property to handle the timing:

```
private refreshInterval$: Observable<string> = timer(0, 1000)
.pipe(
  // This kills the request if the user closes the component 
  takeUntil(this.killTrigger),
  // switchMap cancels the last request, if no response have been received since last tick
  switchMap(() => this.fetchData$),
  // catchError handles http throws 
  catchError(error => of('Error'))
);
```

At last, fire the kill command if the component is killed:

```
ngOnDestroy(){
  this.killTrigger.next();
}
```

Here is a [**StackBlitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxzvkj?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Answer (score 47):

Try with `timer` from RxJS :

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { MyService } from 'path/to/the/service/my-service.service';

@Component({
  ......
})
export class MyExampleComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    subscription: Subscription;
    statusText: string;
    
    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = timer(0, 10000).pipe(
          switchMap(() => this.myService.checkdata())
        ).subscribe(result => this.statusText = result);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

`interval(10000)` from RxJS is not appropriate, because it will start to emit values ONLY after 10sec and not immediatly for the first time (and I think that's not what you're looking for).

However, `timer(0, 10000)`, will emit values immediatly (0) and every 10sec (10000) until unsubscription.

Comment: Nice tip, it's clean and beautiful

Answer (score 2):

The rxjs way to do this would be the following.

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs/observable/interval';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const timeInterval$ = interval(10000);

timeInterval$.pipe(
  map( () => this.http.get(//some url);
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your checkData method you could do something like this:

```
import { timer, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

checkData() {
    return timer(0, 10000)
        .pipe(
           switchMap(_ => this.http.get('my url')),
           catchError(error => of(`Bad request: ${error}`))
        );
}
```

Then your subscribe will get the result of the http call every 10 seconds.

Comment: This seems to work but as soon as there's an error ...ie: no internet connection or cannot find data it will stop looping

Comment: Updated with catch for the error if one occurs in the http request

Comment: This works for a single value , but when there is a parameter passed to the http method , it is remembering all the previous values passed ang giving results for all the values passed till now , which is wrong .

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
export class YourComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private alive: boolean;

  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.alive = true;
    TimerObservable.create(0, 10000)
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(() => this.alive)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.myservice.checkdata().subscribe( result => { this.statustext = result } );
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.alive = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am referring to angular 8:

Please note the difference between timer and interval.

You would use the timer if you want to delay a single function call but you want to use an invertal if you want to fire multiple function calls in sequence with a delay between: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/timeout-interval.html

I found the following code snipped in this blog post: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/timeout-interval.html

```
ngOnInit() {
    interval(5000)
      .pipe(
        startWith(0),
        switchMap(() => this.apiService.getTweets())
      )
      .subscribe(res => this.statuses = res.statuses})
    ;
  }
```

Comment: You are referring to Angular 8 but provide examples for AngularJS? :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use the setInterval which is quite simple

```
setInterval(console.log('hi'), 10000);
```

This runs for every 10 secs