# Angular 6 run a function in every X seconds

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a function called

`opensnack(text) { ... };`

which is opening an [angular material snackbar](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview) with the given text input.

What I want to do is to call this function like every 10 seconds.

How should I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @SiddAjmera https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585764/angular-6-run-method-is-service-every-10-seconds/50585902 I'm trying these, but couldn't get it to work yet

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use **[`interval`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html)** from `rxjs`

Here's how:

```
import { interval, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

subscription: Subscription;

...

//emit value in sequence every 10 second
const source = interval(10000);
const text = 'Your Text Here';
this.subscription = source.subscribe(val => this.opensnack(text));

...

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use **[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)** which is available as method on the Window Object. So you don't need to import anything to use it.

```
intervalId = setInterval(this.opensnack(text), 10000);

...

ngOnDestroy() {
  clearInterval(this.intervalId);
}
```

Here's a [**SAMPLE STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interval-eg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Do I need to import something to use SetTimeout? Because it gives me some errors like this

Comment: My bad, that was a typo. I meant `setInterval` Since it is available as an API on the Window Object, you don't really need to import anything to use it.

Comment: Maybe I ducked up something, but doesn't seem to work. Can I ask you, to have a look? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enzk8t

Comment: Just added a Sample Stackbliz for your ref. Please have a look at it and let me know if that works for you. Please do read the comments carefully though :)

Comment: ngOnDestroy is part of OnDestroy interface. Dont forget to implement.

Comment: There is an error present in the stackblitz. "No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(handler: TimerHandler, timeout?: number, ...arguments: any[]): number', gave the following error."

Comment: @hellmit100, it will work if you make your callback parameter an arrow function.
 () => this.addNum() 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bgb963?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Remember to remove the interval after it's completed as well. If you only unsubscribe the subscription the interval will still keep running every X seconds. I prefer using `takeUntil`, for example: `this. subscription = interval(10000).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(() => { doStuff(); })` and remove it: `ngOnDestroy() { this.destroy$.next(); this.destroy$.complete(); }` where the `this.destroy$` is `Subject`: `private destroy$: Subject<any> = new Subject();`

Comment: If I declare source as a Subscription I get "Type 'Observable<number>' is missing the following properties from type 'Subscription': closed, _parentOrParents, _subscriptions, unsubscribe, and 2 more."

Comment: @Gaspa79 did you call the `subscribe` method?

Answer (score 9):

You can make use of `rxjs` library to run a function every X seconds.

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

 interval(1000)
    .pipe(takeWhile(() => !stop))
    .subscribe(() => {
      // place you code here
    });
```

The above code snippet will execute the subscribed statements every 1 second, until the `stop` condition becomes true.

Comment: import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';

constructor(        

    ) {
       
        this.createNewFutureCostingSNotifier();
    }


public createNewFutureCostingSNotifier() {
        console.log('createNewFutureCostingSNotifier()');
        interval(1)
            .pipe(takeWhile(() => false))
            .subscribe(() => {
                console.log('createNewFutureCostingSNotifier() is now working!');
            });
    }

But not working.

Comment: @RejwanulReja you have set your stop condition to directly to false

Answer (score 6):

Try to use `setInterval`

`setInterval` will allow to run a function regularly with the interval between the runs

https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval

**Example:**

```
function opensnack(text: string) : void {
  console.log(text);
}

setInterval(opensnack, 10000, "my text"); <-- run every 10 second
```

You can look at this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-setinterval-templateside-lckduc?file=app/app.component.ts):

Answer (score 1):

**Angular 6 run a function in every X seconds**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h2>
      Now {{time | date: 'hh:mm:ss'}}
      
      <hr /> 
      Now {{time$ | async | date: 'hh:mm:ss'}}
    </h2>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  time: Date;
  time$;

  constructor() {
    // First way: manual subscribe
    Observable
      .interval(1000)
      .map(() => new Date())
      .subscribe(res => this.time = res)

    // Angular way: by using the `async` pipe
    this.time$ = Observable.interval(1000).map(() => new Date())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class AComponent implements OnInit {
  id: string = "1";
  mySub: Subscription;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.mySub = interval(8000).subscribe((func => {
      this.onIdSelect(this.id);
    }))
  }    
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  onIdSelect(id) {
    this.http.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', id).subscribe((res => {
      console.log(res);
    }))
    // this.mySub.unsubscribe(); 
  }
}
```

Import the interval and Subscription from `rxjs`.
Here, code is calling the `onIdSelect()` method every `8seconds`. So post response will be printed on the console after every `8seconds`. If you want to call the method only once after `8seconds`, then just unsubscribe the `mySub` variable.