# Call api every 2 seconds with file id from the array

Tags: angular

I want to call the `verifyFile` api every 2 seconds for which I have put set interval.
I have used for loop to access the individual file id because there could be many and you can only send it one at a time.
I think set interval inside for loop is not working as expected. Is there a way to do it without the for loop.

```
 checkFileStatus() {
    for (let index = 0; index < this.currentlyRunning.length; index++) {
      const fileId = this.currentlyRunning[index].id;
       let repeat = setInterval(() => {
       let file_id = {
         userFileId: fileId
       }
       console.log(file_id)
       this.auth.verifyFile(file_id).subscribe((res: any)=>{ 
       console.log(res);
       if(res.percent === 100) {
        clearInterval(repeat);
        this.updateFileHistory();
       }
     },(err)=>{ console.log(err)});
     }, 2000);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Ok, what did you try? What's not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 - run method is service every 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585764/angular-6-run-method-is-service-every-10-seconds)

Comment: [**Try with `timer` from RxJS**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50585902/3937794)